# How to print / access Django IntegerChoice human readable labels with Model definition

Tags: python, django, django-models

For the Django Model inherited from IntegerChoices with following human readable strings :

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    class Answer(models.IntegerChoices):
        NO = 0, _('No')
        YES = 1, _('Yes')
        
        __empty__ = _('(Unknown)')


    answer = models.IntegerField(choices=Answer.choices)

    SomeModel.objects.create(answer=0)
    somemodel = SomeModel.objects.filter(answer=0)

    print("Answer : {0}", **somemodel.answer.label** )
```

How can I access the human-readable 'No' and 'Yes' text via using somemodel.answer.xxx ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the name of the field in the model is *`foo`*, then you can access this with the [**`.get_foo_display()`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display).

So if the model looks like:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    class Answer(models.IntegerChoices):
        NO = 0, _('No')
        YES = 1, _('Yes')
        
        __empty__ = _('(Unknown)')


    answer = models.IntegerField(choices=Answer.choices)
```

Then you can access the human readable form of a `MyModel` object *`somemodel`* with:

```
somemodel.get_answer_display()
```

Comment: Thanks @Willem, I actually intend to access the value of the objects single instance, a row from the model. How can I achieve that ?

Comment: @SuperEye: well based on the updated question, `somemodel` is a model object, and you thus access it with `somemodel.get_answer_display()`, this will thus return `_('No')` or `_('Yes')`.

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't understand in the first place, but now it is visible somemodel.get_XXX_display() where XXX refers to the integerchoices inherited model. Thanks again.